# Laravel point type store works fine but retrieving data gives incorrect result

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, point, collation

I'm storing Point data type in the database [image]

it works fine when storing data.

but when I want to get all data from the database even with Tinker, the location column data is incorrect.

[image]

I don't know what to do!
I'm not using any packages to convert latitude and longitude to Point type.

Comment: You might want to look into something like https://github.com/grimzy/laravel-mysql-spatial.

Comment: not compatible with Laravel 10

Comment: https://github.com/grimzy/laravel-mysql-spatial/issues/203#issuecomment-1457181133

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`POINT(26.0, 30.1)` does the conversion for you.  However, note that it is a function with two args separated by a comma.  (Longitude first).

```
mysql> select POINT(26.0, 30.1);
+------------------------------------------------------+
| POINT(26.0, 30.1)                                    |
+------------------------------------------------------+
| 0x0000000001010000000000000000003A409A99999999193E40 |
+------------------------------------------------------+
```

Yes, that gibberish is the 25-byte representation of that point on the globe (in the Siwa desert?)